# Как исходный код на jQuery выглядит на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть код на jQuery, но я хочу разобраться, как он работает и как выглядит на чистом JS. Можете мне пожалуйста помочь, сконцентрировав его в JS?

```
<script>
        $('img.svg').each(function() {
            var $img = $(this);
            var imgID = $img.attr('id');
            var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

            $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);

            }, 'xml');

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Это называется перепишите за меня

Answer (score 1):

`$` в JQ похож на "чистый" `document.querySelectorAll`;

`each()` можно заменить на "чистый" `forEach()`;

`attr()` это `getAttribute()`, `setAttribute()` и т.д.

`$.get` это `var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open("GET", "%URL%", true);` ... и т.д.

`replaceWith` это `removeChild` и `appendChild` (возможно еще пара методов)

А вообще всегда можно заглянуть в код дев версии jq и посмотреть что там происходит под капотом.